# Why can't I transfer USDT to my smartcontract?

Tags: solidity

When I call transferUSDT i got a  'BEP20: transfer amount exceeds balance' but i know i got suffisent funds. I think i miss something in my smart contract.. Here the error on the bscscan:

https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x3a253a8c32ed19bdbed66499ec2f888eae5114d44eba7c2f28a185258e91641f

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

abstract contract IUSDT{
    function approve(address _spender, uint _value) virtual external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) virtual public;
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) virtual external returns (bool);
}

contract usdtTransfer{
    IUSDT TetherContract;
    
    function transferUSDT(uint256 amount) public {
        TetherContract.transfer(address(this),amount);
    }
    
    constructor(address _tetherAddress){
        TetherContract=IUSDT(_tetherAddress);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TetherContract.transfer(address(this),amount);
```

This snippet is trying to transfer `amount` (2nd argument) of tokens to the `address(this)` (1st argument) address - which is the address of the `usdtTransfer` contract.

And since it's executed from the `usdtTransfer` contract, it's trying to send the tokens **from** the very same `usdtTransfer` address.

If your goal is to send the tokens from the user to your contract, the user needs to first execute the `approve()` function on the token contract (from their address, passing your address as the `spender` param).

Comment: thank you so much. it works !